# android.annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to run a sample android code in eclipse, but when I try:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
```

I keep getting an error related to this line like:

```
the import android.annotation cannot be resolved
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Wich API do you Refered in your project.

Because

android.annotation.SuppressLint - it's since Added in API level 16

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint.html

You need do next

You project rigth mouse click->Properties and check next picture for you select Project Build Target for API Level >=16

[image]

Comment: Thanks , seems like that's the problem . but when I open my SDK manager , it doesn't give me any option to upgrade to API level more than 13 . do I have to download my sdk again ?

Comment: Yes, you need run android sdk manager to chekout updates. After that you must run Eclipse Update software for ADT Plugin updates.

Comment: This issue also appeared when importing libraries, for example the Facebook SDK. For some reason it was set to build at a lower level than my main project. I had an error on the libproject only, not my main app and had to change the build path just for the SDK for it to work.

Answer (score 21):

As Artem suggested, you may need to include the annotations.jar file into your project, but note that there are two annotations.jar files in your Android SDK:

**android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar** - Which includes the following annotations:

- SuppressLint
- TargetApi

**android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/annotations.jar** - Which includes many other annotations:

- AnimRes
- AnimatorRes
- AnyRes
- ArrayRes
- AttrRes
- BoolRes
- ColorRes
- DimenRes
- DrawableRes
- FractionRes
- IdRes
- IntDef
- IntegerRes
- InterpolatorRes
- LayoutRes
- MenuRes
- NonNull
- Nullable
- PluralsRes
- RawRes
- StringDef
- StringRes
- StyleRes
- StyleableRes
- XmlRes

Answer (score 12):

In your `android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar`, it  contains the `android.annotation.SuppressLint` and `android.annotation.TargetApi's`  definition.

Answer (score 2):

Dmitry Nelepov's answer is correct, though sometimes your project is already on the desired Project Build Target (this happened in my case). Simply switch the build case to a different one, press "OK", then redo the steps to set it back to the right Project Build Target.