# annotation missing from my extras/android/support/ folder

Tags: android

I have downloaded facebook(project) and I am getting a error android.support.annotation.Nullable( cannot be resolved). Following this link 
[android.annotation cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870596/android-annotation-cannot-be-resolved).  They mentioned there is 2 annotations jar files. I have this one android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar but I don't have this one android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/annotations.jar. (and this one has the •Nullable that I require)
What is the correct way to add this to my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I have added it and cleaned my project, still nothing has changed should I do something else?

Comment: Which IDE you are using Android studio or Eclipse?                                    1. If you are using eclipse you need to add the android-library project in you application.

Comment: Eclipse, Can you please tell me how to add it and where I can download the required fields

Comment: Add the android-support-annotations.jar in your Project  Path of the file is :- android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar

Comment: where can I download it? and should I create that path manually? because I don't have that path.

Comment: You have Android sdk install in you PC in that you will get this extras folder

Comment: In my SDK manager I have installed  android support repositrory and android support library both under extra but I still have the error that I mentioned top. Is it possible to provide me with the steps

Comment: In Eclipse go to window --> Perspective --> select Android and you will get SDK path where android SDK is install in your PC go to that path and find the jar file android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar