# Switch.java has errors in android studio

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I installed android studio in ubuntu recently and I'm pretty new to linux. I built an app that uses a switch widget. The problem is, when I tried to access the switch object using

```
Switch switch = (Switch) findViewByID(R.id.switch1);
```

I got an error saying that it is not a valid statement along with multiple errors like '(' expected, right after the the object name, the second word in the line, 'switch'

Out of curiosity, I went to Switch.java by ctrl clicking the class name. And over there I found over 72 errors.

This is what it looks like:

[image: 73 errors in Switch.java]

I have downloaded the latest google APIs after seeing the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870596/android-annotation-cannot-be-resolved). And I still don't know how to rectify it. I am asking this question here as a last resort. It most probably will be some silly mistake on my part while configuring the install. Please help me!

Comment: Off the bat, pretty sure annotations has to be explicitly added to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` is a [Java language keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) so you can't use it as a variable name.