# android.annotation cannot be resolved IntDef and NonNull

Tags: android

I'm trying to run a sample android code in Andriod Studio, but when I try:

```
import android.annotation.IntDef;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
```

keep getting an error related to this line like:

```
the import android.annotation cannot be resolved
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Comment: Just met the similar problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately no,Even if I uninstalled Android...

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you work with the support annotations:
add this dependency to your project and see if it works:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
```

Comment: still didn't work...Normally I did not have this problem since I update the SDK to 26

Comment: Can you Invalidate the cache from files > Invalidate Caches and see if it works

Comment: Sir, I did what u said but in vain :/ ...what can i do now ?

Answer (score 1):

accourding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252858/1718042) you can use
android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar - Which includes the following annotations:

SuppressLint
TargetApi
android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/annotations.jar - Which includes many other annotations:

AnimRes
AnimatorRes
AnyRes
ArrayRes
AttrRes
BoolRes
ColorRes
DimenRes
DrawableRes
FractionRes
IdRes
IntDef
IntegerRes
InterpolatorRes
LayoutRes
MenuRes
NonNull
Nullable
PluralsRes
RawRes
StringDef
StringRes
StyleRes
StyleableRes
XmlRes

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and came across this question but was not answered.
I could resolve this issue by following steps mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/getting-started#use_a_jetpack_library_in_your_app).
After this, You shall sync the project with Gradle files.
**Note**: You may not find the same annotation path
e.g. `import android.annotation.NonNull; --> import androidx.annotation.Nullable;`